# Installing new OS on laptop from bootable USB/DVD

Tags: ubuntu, boot, installation, multi-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 from a bootable USB drive (created using unetbootin). After setting the boot priority and booting, the screen shows:

```
SYSLINUX 3.63 debian..... 
boot:
```

...and then nothing happens.

Ubuntu 9.04 is already installed in the system and is working fine.

How can I install a new OS?

Comment: any reason you are not installing 12.04 or 13.10?

Comment: Post `syslinux.cfg` from that USB.